# How to get CPU Utilization number from top?

Tags: linux, unix

How would I get the number for CPU Utilization from running the top command on a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe `top` to `awk` and add up the CPU utilization column:

```
top -b -n 1 -u username | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }'
```

That `awk` command says "For rows (from top) greater than row 7, add up the number in field 9 `$9` and store it in variable `sum`. Once you have gone through all of the rows in the piped `top` command, print out the value in variable `sum`".

---

If the `-u` flag isn't working on your system, you can just stick the username search with the `NR>7` condition:

```
 top -b -n 1 | awk 'NR>7 && $2=="root" { sum += $9 } END { print sum }'
```

---

If you wanted to print the percent used for each user listed in top, you could chuck that second condition and switch sum to be an array:

```
 top -b -n 1 | awk 'NR>7 {users[$2]+=($9)} END {for(user in users){print user,users[user]}}'
```

---

One last thing. I believe that the percent cpu may need to be divided by the number of cores in your system. Like... I believe it might be possible to see a number greater than 100 pop up here.

Comment: Thank you! Why the For rows (from top) greater than row 7? Just wondering..

Comment: Run the `top` command without the pipe. You'll see the list of processes starts on Row 8. So we start adding up the amount of CPU being used starting at row 8 until the end.

Comment: I am getting unknown argument u, so I am wondering if I can instead only add to sum if the user equals username. How could I do that?

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I've updated the answer with a version that doesn't require the `-u` flag.